# Writing a rake task to amend current string while preserving the rest of the string Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rake, rake-task

I am trying to write a rake task that will remove part of a string while preserving the rest. I tried chomp and slice, but was unable to get it to work. Below is the current rake task and the string as it appear in my DB. Currently, it will just replace the entire string with whatever is listed in the pets column. That is not my objective. I need to remove the reference to pets while keeping the remainder of the string in the amenities column.

fix_pets.rake

```
namespace :listings do
  desc 'Update old pets in DB'
    task fix_pets: :environment do
      Listing.all.each do |listing|
        if listing.amenities == "All pets ok"
          listing.update(amenities: listing.pets)
        elsif listing.amenities == "Pets upon approval"
          listing.update(amenities: listing.pets)
        end
      end
   end
end
```

amenities in the DB:

"Central A/C All pets ok Hardwood floors"

After the rake task, the amenities field should only have:

"Central A/C Hardwood floors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better to use `include?` if you want to conditionally change the string.

```
if listing.amenities.include? 'All pets ok '
  listing.update(amenities: listing.amenities.gsub('All pets ok ', ''))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try gsub if you want to remove specific matched string only
I'll give a simple example, suppose.

```
match_str="All pets ok"
str1 = "Central A/C All pets ok Hardwood floors"
```

then

```
str2= str1.gsub( match_str, "")
```

or if you wnt to change the original string

```
str1.gsub!( match_str, "")
```

and you will get your string as

"Central A/C Hardwood floors"

You can update your rake task accordingly, its just for reference